# Curly braces to new line - Prettier

Tags: prettier

So, I'm making a excercise to college in C

I like to use Prettier, and I never know how to
tell Prettier to don't push curly braces to new
line.

I want this

```
if (x > y) {
  // Code
}
```

Instead

```
if (x > y)
{
  // Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding Prettier:**

Prettier doesn't allow you to change that setting. They are an "opinionated" formatting extension, and you subscribe to their opinions when you use it.

I unfortunately don't know C, so I can't tell you how to fix it in your specific case.

**However**,

For everyone that came to this post looking for the **C# answer** in VSCode:

1. Locate your `.editorconfig` files in your project
   [Locating .editorconfig files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NG2t.png)
2. Add the following line to the config files for both dotnet 5 and 6:

   `csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = all`
3. File > Preferences > Settings
4. Enable Editor Config Support
   [Enabling editor config support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ElZl.png)
5. Enable Roslyn Analyzers
   [Enabling Roslyn Analyzers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOzQj.png)
6. Make sure your default formatter in VScode is "C#"
   [Setting the default formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCNZW.png)
7. Restart VS Code and the Omnisharp server
   [Restarting the Omnisharp server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAEZ2.png)

Additionally, see all formatting options which can be added to the `.editorconfig` file below:

[Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/formatting-rules)